# how to meet a condition before going on to the next step?

Tags: ruby, loops

how do I loop if a condition is not met?

```
print "Please enter first number "
first_number = gets.chomp 

if first_number =~ /[a-zA-Z]/ 
puts "not a number"
end
```

As per the code posted above, if you enter a letter, you'll get the statement of it not being a number.

How do I repeat it, if a user enters a letter?

As of now, it goes to the next one which is this:

```
 print "Please enter second number "
 second_number = gets.chomp
 if second_number =~ /[a-zA-Z]/
   puts "not a number"
 end
```

I don't want it to it to go to the next one, *until* the user has entered a number in the first one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, hm. that's a good solution too. but what i'm also aiming for here, though not noted explicitly in post above is to also be able to tell user that they entered in a letter if they did that and to loop again until otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use while and until as a modifier to a block. This will run the block first and then check a conditional and run the block again until it passes, which is the behavior you want.

```
begin
  puts 'Please enter first number'
  first_number = gets.chomp
end until first_number =~ /\d+/
```

Comment: thanks! Oy vey, really? I have to put in at least 15 characters?!?!?! Geez!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider doing it like this:

```
num = nil # initialize to anything
loop do
  puts 'Enter a number'
  num = gets.chomp.strip
  case num
  when /^\d+$/
    break
  when /^[a-z]+$/i
    print "You entered one or more letters and no digits."
  else
    print "You made some other illegal entry."
  end
  puts "  Try again"
end
puts "You enterered the number #{num}"
```

Some notes:

- `num` must be initialized (to anything) before the loop in order for it to be visible after the loop's `end` statement.
- the `case` statement, since it uses `===` for evaluating `when` expressions, allows you to enter a regex for each case.
- `^` and `$` in the regexes are anchors, so that, for example, `"34b" =~ /^\d+$/ => nil` (what I assume you want), rather than `"34b" =~ /\d+/ => 0`.
- the `i` in `/[a-z]+$/i` allows matching letters to be uppercase or lowercase.
- the user may enter one or more digits, or one or more letters, but there are many other possibilities as well (`"3$,a"`), so I added another "catch-all" possibility in the `case` statement.